# Marmalade with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: marmalade, visual-studio-2015

I'm starting to learn how to use Marmalade with Visual Studio (and am very much a newbie at this). Earlier I had VS 2013 installed and I could click on a mkb file to make VS 2013 launch containing the project defined in the mkb file. Now, foolishly perhaps, I have installed VS 2015 preview. Now this launch no longer works - no surprise I suppose - and of course the Marmalade Hub reports that there is no Visual Studio 2013.

Does anyone happen to know how to get Marmalade to work with VS 2015?

Comment: Can't see what this got down-voted. It's a perfectly reasonable question. Can you configure marmalade to generate a project suitable for dev in VS 2015? Perhaps those who down voted it would care to tell me why this is not a reasonable question to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with `procmon` a little, I have found that Marmalade's build system just checks for `devenv.exe` in the usual location and uses it.

Since the release notes for the VS2015 CTP specifically recommend not to install it side-by-side with VS2013, I assume you do not have VS2013 installed.
You have VS2015, Marmalade works with VS2013.

Conclusion: Fool Marmalade into thinking you have VS2013 installed, but make it use VS2015 instead.

Steps:

1. Create the registry entry `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Setup\dbghelp_path` and set it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\`
2. Create the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`
3. In the hub, set your IDE to VS2013 (or in your mkb add `option buildenv="VC12"`)
4. Run the mkb, then open the resulting solution (found in `build_xxx_vc12\xxx_vs12.sln`) in VS2015

**BONUS** actually make that fake `devenv.exe` a launcher which runs VS2015's devenv.exe

It's ugly and I haven't tried all the steps together, but it should work.
Until Marmalade supports VS2015, that's all I've got.
It's a shame their build system is so closed and restrictive, but good their checks are so simple.

Alternatively you can make `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\` an NTFS link to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\`, but that may create more problems in the long-run than it solves.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a workable solution. For the moment I've gone back to the earlier version of VS - not being so 'bleeding edge' - but when I get some spare time I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Marmalade 7.9, released a few days ago (September 2015) support Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Marmalade is not really supported on VS2013, except for Windows Phone/Store 8.1, let alone 2015.

I would suggest you install VS2010 or VS2012 express (the latter for Desktop). They should live alone the VS2015 without issue. You can setup Marmalade to use the old version and use 2015 for other stuff. Note that if you are targetting Android or iOS, it does not really matter that you switch to an older version - the real compilers are included with the Marmalade SDK.

Comment: After having worked on a cross-platform Marmalade (SDK 7.4) project using VS2013 for a month, I can tell you it works well. We as a team used VS 2010/2013 Express, 2012 Professional, 2013 Ultimate and XCode all on the same codebase without a problem.

Comment: That is useful. I can however tell you that there are issues with VS2013. If you've avoided them, then good.

Comment: Can you point out the issues with VS2013 or provide a link? I will stay away from Marmalade in the future (for other reasons), but I am sure other users would benefit from some pointers.

Comment: We are currently fixing some VS2013 issues, so should be OK soon. They include that when you compile for arm, the compilation is never incremental, and a few similar issues. Also some of the examples don't work because the run-time is missing a font they use that was available previously - or at least the font is not found.